# How to amend a WordPress site's URL?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have setup my site with 5 pages which are my menu options.

When running my WordPress site on my local host using MAMP, my url is:

http://localhost:8888/mySite/ or http://www.example.com/ (when I go live)

When I click on a menu item, it changes the URL to:

http://localhost:8888/mySite/MenuOptionA or http://www.example.com/mySite/MenuOptionA

How can I setup a Permalink or something else, so that it always just shows my main URL above without the /MenuOptionA when I have click on any menu options?

I basically would like my url to always just show http://www.example.com/ no matter what menu option is selected.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hi, I guess I don't have to do this but from what I can currently see, I don't understand why some of my menu options display in the URL and others don't - any ideas here?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change you're site's url easily by adding in the following statements into wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.mySite.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.mySite.com/');
```

If you don't want to maintain two different config files, you can put a conditional in there to determine what value to use.